Cannot install nvtop in Kubuntu 24.04 from the official repositories
I am trying to install nvtop, which is in the official repositories https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvtop. But apt cannot locate the package.
$ sudo apt install nvtop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvtop

My sources.list seems to be alright
$ cat sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble main universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security universe main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates universe main

I have been using this system for several months, and never had any other package manager issue. How to debug this issue and install nvtop?

You have to enable multiverse
apt policy nvtop
nvtop:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 3.0.2-1
Version table:
  3.0.2-1 500
     500 http://ubuntu.mirror.su.se/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 Packages

sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update

from: How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?

Whoever downvoted can you explain the downvote?
